# Letting the user define the arguments in a custom loop? (the "$custom_posts->query(...)" part)

Tags: custom-post-types

I use the following to retrieve a post from a custom post type and custom taxonomies:

```
<?php // Create and run custom loop
    $custom_posts = new WP_Query();
    $custom_posts->query('post_type=blocks&location=Front Page&section=Mainbar');
    while ($custom_posts->have_posts()) : $custom_posts->the_post();
?>
    <div class="block-2 border-top">
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

In the Page, I want to create fields that will let the user customize the loop arguments like this:

```
$custom_posts->query('post_type=blocks&location=<Enter Location>&section=<Enter Section>');
```

What's the easiest way of doing this?

How would that code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way would be to create a simple form :

```
<?php $nonce= wp_create_nonce  ('my-nonce'); ?>
<form name="user-query" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpnonce" id="_wpnonce" value="<?php echo $nonce; ?>"/>
<p>Locations:
<select name="location" id"location">
  <option value="location1">location1</option>
  <option value="location2">location2</option>
  <option value="location3">location3</option>
  <option value="location4">location4</option>
</select></p>
<p>Sections:
<select name="section" id"location">
  <option value="section1">section1</option>
  <option value="section2">section2</option>
  <option value="section3">section3</option>
  <option value="section4">section4</option>
</select></p>
<input type="submit" name="create-query" value="create query"/>
</form>
```

and catch that for submit and process

```
if (isset($_POST['create-query'])){
    $nonce=$_POST['_wpnonce'];
    if (! wp_verify_nonce($nonce, 'my-nonce') ) die('Security check');
    if (isset($_POST['location']) && isset($_POST['section']) ){
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'blocks',
            'location' => $_POST['location'],
            'section' => $_POST['section']
        );
        $custom_posts->query($args);
    }
}
```

and i would add some security checks but this should get you going.

Comment: Missing a `$` on your nonce var in the second code sample mate.. ;)

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit beginner, Where and how should I add/hook that code?

Comment: the first part is the form where the user selects the location and section. the second code is the processing of the form.